# Download File with an a-tag Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi my Question is how can I handle a Download in Play Framework
my Code is in JAVA.

```
User user = User.find.byId(Long.parseLong(id));
    File tempFile = null;
    try {
        tempFile = File.createTempFile(user.attachment_name, ".zip", null);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        fos.write(user.attachment);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return ok(tempFile);
```

but I dont know how I can handel the resonse of the return on the HTML View that I can download it with a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `Result` function for downloading the content. E.g:

```
public static Result download(String id) throws IOException {
  User user = User.find.byId(Long.parseLong(id));
    File tempFile = null;
    try {
        tempFile = File.createTempFile(user.attachment_name, ".zip", null);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        fos.write(user.attachment);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ok(tempFile);
}
```

Routes: `GET  /download  controllers.Application.download(id)`

If you have a download link for an item, its `href` should be `href="@routes.Application.download(id)"`. You need to pass `id`(I believe you use id of user) to view to be able to use `id`

You might need to add `ContentType` and `Content disposition`.

```
response().setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=yourFileName.pdf");
```

Other option is that play framework supports [serving files](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaStream#Serving-files). If you have already a file in a folder, you can just specify the path and let the framework do the process.

```
public Result index() {
    return ok(new java.io.File("/tmp/fileToServe.pdf"));
}
```